# Order by case with NULLs not first nor last

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to order a query by an enum, where 2 values of my enum i want to have the same priority, but also i want NULLs to be mixed in there, rather than first.

I'm using a case when syntax with OR operators to concat the same level of priority between them, it seems to work just fine except for the NULLs, which aren't properly ordered in, they seem random.

```
CASE
  WHEN company_size = 0 OR
   company_size = 1 OR
   company_size = NULL THEN '0'
  WHEN company_size = 2 THEN '1'
  WHEN company_size = 3 THEN '2'
END
```

Help please

Comment: order by a numeric value rather a character or string.

Answer (score 2):

`NULL = NULL` evaluates to NULL, not to true.  In a CASE WHEN expression, NULL has the same outcome as false does.  To mingle the NULL in with the 1 and 0, You probably want this:

```
CASE
  WHEN company_size = 0 OR
   company_size = 1 OR
   company_size is NULL THEN '0'
  WHEN company_size = 2 THEN '1'
  WHEN company_size = 3 THEN '2'
END
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `order by coalesce()`

```
select * from tableA
order by coalesce(company_size, 0)
```